# Clicking a button and displaying a javascript function on same page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to html and javascript. How can I display the for loop that I have in my javascript function on the same page upon clicking the button. Right now I click the button and it brings me to a whole different page displaying 0 to -99. I want the numbers to appear below the button on the same page. Any ideas?

```
         <fieldset>
         <legend>Loop Until -99</legend>
         <form name="loopuntil99" method="post">
         <input type="button" value="Display -99" onclick="displayArray()" />
         </form>
         </fieldset>

         </body>

         <script type="text/javascript">
       function displayArray()
       {

      for (i=0;i>-100;i--)
      {

    document.write(i + ", ");

       } 
        }

    </script>

     </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a div and just modify the HTML in that.

```
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function displayArray()
{
    var div = document.getElementById("output");
    div.innerHTML = "0";
    for (i=-1;i>-100;i--)
    {
        div.innerHTML += ", " + i;
    } 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks it works. Would this be the simplest way to do this? b/c I need to create some kind of basic menu. I need to allow the user to enter 10 numbers and put it into array. With that array I need to display different things like reverse order, sort ,ect.. So I guess what I'm asking is would I need to createa <div id/> for each different function I would want to print out?

Comment: Or better yet, lets say I click another button that calls a different function that will have a different output. How would I update and replace output with the results from the second function

Comment: You can add as many divs as you need. You reference the div in JavaScript using the `id` in `document.getElementById`, then set the `innerHTML` property like above.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are outside the `<body>` tag.  Place that code before the `</body>` tag and try again.